How can I determine the frequency range of the relay in the RF range without accurate data in the documentation?
Please tell me how to determine in which frequency range the relay operates, if the description for it indicates that it operates in the RF range, but the documentation does not name the exact frequency? As I read on this forum, there are no specific standards for determining the frequency range, then the question is even more problematic
As an example, I give a Panasonic photo relay: 1) AQY221N3MY 2) AQY225R2S. In the first relay, there is a frequency dependence of losses, where the graph is plotted up to 10 Mhz, and in the second there is nothing at all...
For my tasks, I need a relay with a maximum frequency of more than 1 Ghz. Can you tell me if there are such things at all?

How much power is there in your 1 GHz signal?

Do you need a solid state or electro-mechanical RF relay (impacts on the switching speed and number of switching operations)? On a random search found New High Frequency / RF Relays on a distributor website which has some devices which might meet your requirements.

@thephoton I need to transmit a signal equal to +-20 V and a current of about 100-150 mA (taking into account reliability), therefore 1 - 3 Wt

@ChesterGillon I am trying to consider less expensive and more compact relays. I have already found a suitable electromechanical relay, now I decided to consider a solid state, because they are more suitable for these criteria.

@ChesterGillon You found a great relay (Menlo Micro MM1205), it looks like I found it at Standox (RM05-8 AS), but it's too expensive :)


Please tell me how to determine in which frequency range the relay
operates

Both Panasonic relays are unsuitable for use at 1 GHz due to the specification of the open-circuit output capacitance. For the better part (item 1), the open-circuit maximum output capacitance is 1.5 pF. A capacitor of 1.5 pF has a reactance of 106 Ω at 1 GHz hence, it would appear to be unsuitable as a switch at these frequencies.
At 10 MHz the open circuit output reactance is over 10 kΩ hence, it will be useful in several types of circuit I suspect. However, you are not stating what sort of output impedance you can live-with so, it's impossible to give better guidance.

For my tasks, I need a relay with a maximum frequency of more than 1
GHz. Can you tell me if there are such things at all?

Your best bet is to choose a mechanical RF relay such as G6K(U)-2F(P)-RF(-S, -T). However, it is quoted as having an open-contact isolation of only 20 dB so it's not a whole lot better than the Panasonic SSRs (I estimate the Panasonic has an isolation of around 10 dB in a 50 Ω circuit).
These reed-relays from Pickering are a significant improvement. They have an open-circuit contact capacitance of about 0.1 pF. This is equivalent to a capacitive reactance of 1590 Ω. That's an isolation of slightly over 30 db in a 50 &ohm circuit.
It ultimately boils down to what you are hoping to achieve of course. It's a numbers-game.
